# Table highlight and display its content upon click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add an extra functionality on my table where users can click on any Rn. This should highlight the whole column and display some hidden content coming from the highlighted column Rn TD. The highlight works fine excepts for some small bugs (e.g. you can click the 'player name' column which shouldn't be the case), but the content that needs to change such as the player names and the race information is not changing..

Also, the prev and next buttons are not working anymore since I added the extra code to make the table highlight work. The working prev/next version can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/yunowork/4UGre/

What am I doing wrong?

DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/yunowork/4UGre/6/

Answer (score 0):

Try it in the last demo:

change:

```
rows.children().click(function() { ...
```

to:

```
rows.children().not('.emptyrace, .race').on('click', function() { ...
//exclude the td with prev and next link
```

We have again some bug (like highlight the R1, R2 element text) but this could be a starting point.